# .NET Framework version causing different behavior between two different machines?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, .net-framework-version

I'm currently trying to debug a weird issue I'm having with some RESTful API calls. I built an Angular 2 scaffold and used the publish feature to create a standalone build which users can run by opening a command prompt and typing in "project --debug" -> this will start the scaffold service and users can submit API calls to retrieve data from files. This works perfectly fine on my machine and I can make the API calls just fine, but I have another computer where the results are different. The other computer always fails and lands in an Exception block when accessing a specific type of file.

I'm wondering if this may have to do with some kind of version mismatch/difference on the .NET Frameworks and/or Microsoft Visual C++ redistributables. The published build (original computer) was built using .NET 4.5.1 while the other computer only has 4.6.1 installed.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation where the exact same build yields different results? I'm currently uninstalling versions of .NET and redistributables to test this hunch out but I'm curious if some of you may have had a similar experience.

Comment: Sure this is possible. Who hasn't heard the line "It works on my machine." ? Do you have any details about the exception or the code that isn't working. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Can you share any code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my issue is related to the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributables - I removed the 2015 redistributables from the original machine (because it turns on the other machine did not have them), and I received the same results. Going deeper, I'm guessing this is because one of the DLLs was built using the 2015 redistributables.